# Maven : What should be the url value under the distributionManagement

Tags: maven-2

I am forced by Maven to specify a url under  tag insde POM.xml file

```
     <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Nexus Staging Repo</name>
      <url>scp://home/maven2/html</url>  
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

I am running mvn deploy to deploy the war file under Tomcat Web-apps
I don't have any domain , what should be the default to be provided here , and the username and the password inside   , so that maven deploys my war into Tomcat .

Comment: According to the documentation of [Maven Deploy Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/), the goal deploy is used to deploy in a Maven repository. Perhaps you will find that information in [How do I deploy a maven web application to Tomcat?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-tomcat.html).

Comment: This is absolutely nonsense from Maven , how can it force to use a repo , and your pointed link says http://localhost:8080/manager/  and for me it shows 404 . So totally nothing is done for me . please anybody help i just want to deploy the Application in tomcat .

Comment: Have you seen the second URL pointing to "How to deploy ... to Tomcat?". There a maven plugin named `tomcat-maven-plugin` with the command `mvn tomcat:deploy` is mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deploy phase in the maven lifecycle refers to deploying artifacts to a maven repository, not deploying artifacts to an application server. If you want to deploy your webapp I suggest you have a look at the maven cargo plugin.

Edit: Just to be extra clear: Deploying webapps to tomcat is not what "mvn deploy" is supposed to do.